# Set C compiler (CC) in R for Windows

Tags: r, compiler-errors, package, devtools

When updating to RStudio 1.2, I had to switch from using 32-bit to a 64-bit version of R.
However, the R C compiler command is still looking to a 32-bit version of MinGW, which means that I can't compile packages for a 64-bit installation.

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling RTools 3.5 and R 3.6.0, and the `PATH` and `BINPREF` environment variables point to the appropriate 64-bit folders.  Nevertheless, R is still looking for a 32-bit C compiler when compiling packages that contain C source code: `R CMD config CC` returns `C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/gcc`, but I can't work out how to change this to `mingw_64`.

As a result, when I run `devtools::install()` (or `check`, `load_all` etc), I'm confronted with an error:

```
* installing *source* package 'MYPACKAGE' ...
** using staged installation
** libs
sh: line 6: C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/nm: No such file or directory
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++ -shared -s -static-libgcc -o MYPACKAGE.dll tmp.def [...] -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.0/bin/x64 -lR
sh: line 8: C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++: No such file or directory
no DLL was created
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'MYPACKAGE'
```

RStudio throws up a dialog box offering to install RTools, but proceeding with the installation doesn't help: the CC path  is unchanged.

Comment: Over on Linux, we'd just specify this in `~/.R/Makevars`; I would be surprised if you could not do something similar on Windows, though I'm not sure where in your file system a user- or system-wide `Makevars.win` should be stored. What was the driving force for using 32-bit R originally?

Comment: R has a `makeconf` file, but that links to mingw_64. I'm trying to remember the reason for originally using 32-bit R ... I remember hitting a similar problem, maybe even this one, when using 64-bit R and thus deciding it would be simpler just to get by with 32-bit.

Comment: Have you tried with `devtools::install('MYPACKAGE', quick = TRUE)`?

Comment: `devtools::install('MYPACKAGE', quick = TRUE)` fails with the same error, as does `R CMD INSTALL MYPACKAGE`.  Adding `CC=C:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/gcc` to `R\R-3.6.0\src\library\windlgs\src\Makevars.win` has made no difference.

Comment: Darn, after checking `?devtools::install` I hoped something about multi-arch build may have been to blame. The only other thing I knew to consult was the R Installation and Administration Guide; [Sec. 6.3.1](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-admin.html#Windows-packages) seems to have a relevant passage (which you may have alluded to earlier): "Packages with compiled code may need to have paths to the compilers set explicitly.... The [] paths are set using the make variables BINPREF and (usually) BINPREF64.... [They] can be set in ... etc/i386/Makeconf or etc/x64/Makeconf...."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of `BINPREF` specified in `C:\Program files\R\R-3.6.0\etc\x64\Makeconf` was being overwritten by a different value that I'd previously specified (by hand, as `/mingw_32/` rather than the preferable `/mingw_$(WIN)/`) in `C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\Documents\.R\Makevars`, which of course survived the uninstallation of R.  Updating this file to point to the 64-bit path resolved the issue.

Thanks to duckmayr for leading me to the answer.

Comment: Congrats on getting it sorted! (+1)